# Is it possible to create a toolbar item without using navigationView/navigationStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, toolbar

See the code below. Using that code I can see the toolbar item without any problem. But if i remove or replace navigationView with for example a VSack the toolbar item disappears.

Is it possible to add a toolbar item without navigationView/navigationStack? I extra interested in the possibility since it may solve my problem with using multiple navigationViews in multiple views connected to each other.

The working code:

> ```
> import SwiftUI
>
> struct Restaurant: Identifiable {
>     let id = UUID()
>     let name: String
> }
>
> // A view that shows the data for one Restaurant.
> struct RestaurantRow: View {
>     var restaurant: Restaurant
>
>     var body: some View {
>         Text("Come and eat at \(restaurant.name)")
>     }
> }
>
> // Create three restaurants, then show them in a list.
> struct SwiftUIView: View {
>     let restaurants = [
>         Restaurant(name: "Joe's Original"),
>         Restaurant(name: "The Real Joe's Original"),
>         Restaurant(name: "Original Joe's")
>     ]
>     
>     var body: some View {
>         NavigationStack {
>             List(restaurants) { restaurant in
>                 RestaurantRow(restaurant: restaurant)
>             }
>             .toolbar {
>                 ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
>                     Text("Great Toolbar")
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
>     static var previews: some View {
>         SwiftUIView()
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The code that doesn't show the toolbar item:

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(restaurants) { restaurant in
                RestaurantRow(restaurant: restaurant)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                    Text("Great Toolbar")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Removed navigationView, replaced it with something else like a VStack.

Comment: I believe the `toolbar` modifier can be used without a `NavigationView`, but its behavior will differ depending on the platform. Have you tried placing it under the `VStack` block instead of `List`? also you may have to pass an explicit value to `placement` other than `.automatic` to see which value results in the `Text` rendering in the UI. If all doesn't work, you could ditch `toolbar` and place the `Text` directly in the `VStack` above the `List`.

Answer (score 8):

On iOS (and iPadOS), the `toolbar` modifier requires an enclosing `NavigationView` or `NavigationStack`. However, as I explained when answering your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75119837/77567), you only need one enclosing `NavigationView`. The `toolbar` modifier will search up the view hierarchy to find it.

Note though that if you present a view in a sheet, you will need a `NavigationView` inside that sheet. The sheet has its own view hierarchy independent of the view that presents the sheet.

Comment: This is where SwiftUI is strange again :( Why is it possible then to add `.navigationTitle` without any wrapping `NavigationView`. In my case adding a `NavigationView` would change the layout.
I might end up putting a button below the bar and translate it upwards :/